# Pandas Column equal to Column minus value in row "Row name"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to do something that I thought would be straightforward but is definitely not for me...

I have a table (called dftl) that look like this:

| Event | Frame | Time | Frame_x | Time_x | Frame_y | Time_y | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Event A | 2 | 270 | --------- | -------- | --------- | -------- | ... |
| Event B | 5 | 420 | --------- | -------- | --------- | -------- | ... |
| Event C | 11 | 570 | --------- | -------- | --------- | -------- | ... |
| Event D | 15 | 980 | --------- | -------- | --------- | -------- | ... |
| Event E | 20 | 1120 | --------- | -------- | --------- | -------- | ... |
| File | Name | Name | Name | Name | Name | Name | ... |

All "Frame" column are filled with numbers of the same range as the first one, same for "Time" columns.

I want to create:
newdftl = dftl[columns] - dftl[columns][Event C]

So for the first Frame column, all rows are equal to their value minus the value in that column in the row corresponding to Event C (for the cell in Frame/Event A it is 2 - 11) like so:

| Event | Frame | Time | Frame_x | Time_x | Frame_y | Time_y | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Event A | -9 | -300 | --------- | -------- | --------- | -------- | ... |
| Event B | -6 | -150 | --------- | -------- | --------- | -------- | ... |
| Event C | 0 | 0 | --------- | -------- | --------- | -------- | ... |
| Event D | 4 | 410 | --------- | -------- | --------- | -------- | ... |
| Event E | 9 | 550 | --------- | -------- | --------- | -------- | ... |
| File | Name | Name | Name | Name | Name | Name | ... |

My guess is that first I will need to get rid or exclude the last row to do that, as those are not numbers. But on top of that I have no clue on how to do my operation.

I also thought about transposing the table thinking it would help me but I still don't know how to make that operation.

Thank you in advance for all your help !

Orohena

Comment: You should remove the last row completely and keep it in a different DataFrame, or `dict`. Pandas can treat different types of data, but works much better if values in the same column are of the same data type.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Event': {0: 'Event A', 1: 'Event B', 2: 'Event C', 3: 'Event D', 4: 'Event E'}, 'Frame': {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 11, 3: 15, 4: 20}, 'Time': {0: 270, 1: 420, 2: 570, 3: 980, 4: 1120}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Code:**

```
df['Frame'] = df['Frame'] - df['Frame'].loc[df['Event'] == 'Event C'].iloc[0]
df['Time'] = df['Time'] - df['Time'].loc[df['Event'] == 'Event C'].iloc[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)

     Event  Frame  Time
0  Event A     -9  -300
1  Event B     -6  -150
2  Event C      0     0
3  Event D      4   410
4  Event E      9   550
```

As per request in comments (apply it to multiple columns):

```
import numpy as np
cols = ['Frame', 'Time']
df[cols] = df[cols] - pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df[df['Event'].eq('Event C')].values,len(df),axis=0), columns=df.columns)[cols]
```

Comment: Thanks ! If I understood correctly, that means 1 line of code for each column I have (as I want to do the same operation on all). Is there a way to do it on all columns in only 1 line of code and which would work if the number of columns vary ?

Comment: @Orohena, yes, but it gets more complicated, see updated answer.

Comment: Wow, it does seem more complicated indeed. I will give it a try. Would it be simpler if I transpose and perform row calculation instead of column calculation or that would be about the same ? Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

you might try something like this, after discarding the last raw:

```
#create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(None, columns= ['Event', 'Measure', 'Measure2'])
df.loc[len(df)] = ['A', 10, 5]
df.loc[len(df)] = ['B', 11, 7]
df.loc[len(df)] = ['C', 15, 8]
df.loc[len(df)] = ['D', 21, 6]
df.loc[len(df)] = ['E', 3, 4]
print(df)

#get the new dataframe
newdf = df 
newdf[['Measure', 'Measure2']] -= newdf[newdf['Event'] == 'C'][['Measure', 'Measure2']].to_numpy()[0]
newdf
```

Comment: Thanks too! I guess that as for Andreas answer, it means 1 line of code for each column I have (as I want to do the same operation on all). Is there a way to do it on all columns in only 1 line of code and which would work if the number of columns vary ?

Comment: You can try the updated version that I posted